# When printing reports I generated some times the table header comes twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

i am using these css

[image]

```
tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

already tried in below properties

```
 thead   {display: table-header-group;   } 
tfoot   {display: table-footer-group;   }
```

My question is that some times the table header comes twice.

Comment: i fix it i am adding margin-top:20px; in my table class now it working fine

Comment: Improved title and added output into the question.